# Get the HTML content of an Angular form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have one angular form like the following

```
<div #myForm [formGroup]="myForm">        
        <select formControlName="productName" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of productNames" [value]="item.value"
                [textContent]="item.text"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button (click)="Print()">Print</button>
```

On button click I want to get the form html so I can use it somewhere else. So I used the form reference to get the innerHtml like the following.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-print-form',
  templateUrl: './print-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./print-form.component.css']
})
export class PrintFormComponent implements OnInit {
  myFormGrp: FormGroup;
  productNames:  any[];
  @ViewChild('myForm') myForm: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productNames = [
      {text: "aaa", value: "1"},
      {text: "bbb", value: "2"},
      {text: "ccc", value: "3"},
      {text: "ddd", value: "4"}
    ];

    this.myFormGrp = this.formBuilder.group({
      productName: new FormControl({ value: '3', disabled: false })
    });
  }

  Print(): void {
     console.log(this.myForm.nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }

}
```

But the innerText doesn't return the selected value of the dropdown. Is there any way to get the selected values of the form controls?

Answer (score -1):

I see you are using reactivform. You should add the `(ngSubmit)` event listener like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="print()">
```

Besides, you shouldn’t use capital letters for your methods `(print() and not Print()`)

Then you can retrieve a value of a form like this:

```
console.log(this.myForm.get('the_value_to_retrieve').value);
```

The angular doc is very detailed: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms